# Keep default behaviour defined in abstract using a different type in the derived class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Using the context of `Models` and `View Models` from `MVVM`, how can I deal with this situation?

I have two abstract classes that will be the base of all models and view models in my program; `BaseModel` and `BaseViewModel`.

They look like the following.

---

```
public abstract class BaseModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel {
    protected readonly BaseModel baseModel;

    public BaseViewModel(BaseModel baseModel) {
        this.baseModel = baseModel;
    }

    public string Name {
        get => baseModel.Name;
        set {
            baseModel.Name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

---

I also have these two classes that will be used with a specific view in my program; `UseableModel` and `UseableViewModel`.

They look like the following.

---

```
public class UseableModel : BaseModel {
    public string NewVar { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class UseableViewModel : BaseViewModel {
    public UseableViewModel(UseableModel model) : base(model) { }

    public string NewVar {
        get => baseModel.NewVar;
        set {
            baseModel.NewVar = value;
        }
    }
}
```

---

The problem is this obviously won't work as `UseableViewModel.NewVar` tries to make reference to a property that doesn't exist in `BaseModel`.

What is the best way to allow every view model to keep the behaviour defined in the `BaseViewModel` but to use its own model that is extended from `BaseModel`?

---

*Potential solutions*

There are several potential solutions such as write a `Name` property in each view model but that could be a lot of duplication depending on how many view model there were.

You could also define a separate model in the view model like

```
//...
private readonly UseableModel model;

public UseableViewModel(UseableModel model) : base(model)
{
    this.model = model
}
//...
```

But then there is the problem of data sets being duplicated and wasting space as well as there being inconsistent data in between the two models.

So is there a way to do that avoids the duplication of method definitions and avoids the issue described immediately above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make BaseModel and BaseViewModel implement generics.  Something like:

```
public abstract class BaseModel<TModel>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseViewModel<TModel> where TModel : BaseModel<TModel>
{
    protected readonly TModel baseModel;

    public BaseViewModel(TModel baseModel)
    {
        this.baseModel = baseModel;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => baseModel.Name;
        set => baseModel.Name = value;
    }
}

public class UseableModel : BaseModel<UseableModel>
{
    public string NewVar { get; set; }
}

public class UseableViewModel : BaseViewModel<UseableModel>
{
    public UseableViewModel(UseableModel model) : base(model) { }

    public string NewVar
    {
        get => baseModel.NewVar;
        set => baseModel.NewVar = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks like precisely what I was after